# separation of the string in .ini file (configparser)

Tags: python, configparser

My ConfigParser.ini file looks like:

```
[Filenames]
Table1={"logs.table2",92}
Table2=("logs.table2",91)
Table3=("audit.table3",34)
Table4=("audit.table4",85)
```

and now for example for Table1, I would like to get "logs.table2" value and 92 as separate variables.

```
import configparser
filename=config.get('FIlenames','Table1')
```

As result I would like to get:

```
print(filename) -> logs.table2
print(filenumber) -> 92
```

For now output is just a string ""logs.table2",92". Truly I have no idea how to handle that, maybe I should modify my config file? 
What is the best aproach?

Comment: You can split values apart using `a, b = str.split()`.  However, if you have mixed `(` and `{` entries as shown in your example, a regular expression may be more suitable.

Comment: So, you receommed to use some function directly on strings ? Is it the best aproach? Maybe I could write my configini.file in different way to easier get that values?

Comment: @ti7, Okay then I will use split function, but how to assign value after comma to other variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing .ini files is getting strings.

> [Filenames]
>
> Table1=logs.table2,92
>
> Table2=logs.table2,91
>
> Table3=audit.table3,34
>
> Table4=audit.table4,85

`table` is a string, so you can split its contents into a list of comma separated values

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
table=config.get('Filenames','Table1')
list_table = table.split(',')
print(list_table[0])
print(list_table[1])
```

But, best practise is to put in separated lines all the name=value pairs:

> [Filenames]
>
> TABLE1_FILENAME = logs.table2
>
> TABLE1_FILENUMBER = 92

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

ConfigParser.ini

```
[Filenames]
Table1.filename=logs.table2
Table1.filenumber=92
Table2.filename=logs.table2
Table2.filenumber=91
Table3.filename=audit.table3
Table3.filenumber=34
Table4.filename=audit.table4
Table4.filenumber=85
```

Code:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('ConfigParser.ini')
print config.get('Filenames', 'Table1.filename')
print config.get('Filenames','Table1.filenumber')
```

Comment: Thanks @tianwei. However I will use split solution.